# mobForest R Package and Model Based Random Forest

Tags: random-forest

I have two covariates and I am using them to predict the response variable using Mobforest_analysis. After prediction, is there a way I can obtain the regression coefficients for both variables along with the intercept. To me, I don't think it can be obtained so I used the Mob.rf.tree function as that is a single tree model and the regression coefficients were obtained. Is this a good way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Random forests, or trees in that matter,  do not estimate any coefficients, neither in classification nor regression. 
Trees simply represent a collection of partitions in the feature space, obtained by recursive binary splitting.